# Missing number, treat as zero

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have this error, and I cannot figure out:

[image]

[image]
    \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

```
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\quad}Xlrr}
    \toprule
     &  & \thead{{\textbf{Statistic}}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Std. Error}}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{\textit{AABC}}}\\
    Mean & & 93434.434 & 2.432 \\

\multirow{}{=}{95\% Confidence of Interval of Mean (\%)}  &  Lower Bound & 44.434 &  \\
     &  Upper Bound & 98.6414 & \\

     5\% Trimmed Mean& & 94.1806 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: your multirow syntax was not correct

Comment: it is not usually a good idea to use `[h]` latex will warn and change it to `[ht]` in most cases, but not including `p` makes it a lot more likely that the table goes to the end of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can you explain more? I could not get your meaning. Do you mean `\begin{table}[htp]`?

Comment: yes or `[htbp]` unless you specifically want to prevent bottom of page.  the option just restricts the places latex will try to place the table so if you restrict it too much it can not place it anywhere so it gets held until dumped by `\clearpage` or end of document (which does `\clearpage` implicitly)

Comment: The directive `\multirow{}{=}{...}` contains a syntax error: The first argument of `\multirow` *must* be an integer, e.g., 1, 2, etc.

Comment: @Mico, thanks, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\quad}Xllrr}
    \toprule
     &  & \thead{{\textbf{Statistic}}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Std. Error}}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{\textit{AABC}}}\\
    Mean & && 93434.4340 & 2.432 \\

\multirow{2}{*}{95\% Confidence of Interval of Mean (\%)} & &  Lower Bound & 44.4340 &  \\
                                &                            &  Upper Bound & 98.6414 & \\

     5\% Trimmed Mean&& & 94.1806 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xllrr}
    \toprule
   &  &  & \thead{{\textbf{Statistic }}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Std. Error}}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{\textit{AABC}}}\\
    Mean & && 93434.4340 & 2.432 \\

{95\% Confidence of Interval of Mean } & &  Lower Bound & 44.4340 &  \\
    (\%)                            &                            &  Upper Bound & 98.6414 & \\

     5\% Trimmed Mean&& & 94.1806 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it works

Comment: would you like to accept the answer

Comment: sorry, i am not sure where to change, but the column is not the same as original. I added a picture of my table

Comment: edited have a look

Comment: thanks. it works. However, can I not force `(\%)` in a  new line?

Comment: if it meets the table drawn in the question may i suggest you accept the answer -- new questions can be asked separately

Comment: thanks. actually for reference, `\multirow{}{=}{...} contains a syntax error: The first argument of \multirow must be an integer, e.g., 1, 2, etc.`